# Why I am not getting all the result in my query code?

Tags: php, mysql, extjs

I am having a problem. The following code works fine in my local, but on the live server, it's not working properly..I was supposed to get two rows, but on the live server I am getting only 1 result.

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `wspm_t_colors`');
$result = mysql_fetch_object($query);
print json_encode($result);
```

What could possibly be the error ?...

Comment: Are you sure that table `wspm_t_colors` have 2 rows?

Comment: If there is a difference between your local and production, its almost always due to the difference in the environments. Check if you are missing something, or if the contents of the database is different.

Comment: yes, i checked the live table, it's the same data and data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is only getting one row. The [`mysql_fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) function only returns one row. You need to try something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `wspm_t_colors`');
$json = array();
while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($query))
    $json[] = $result;
print json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe you get two rows with this, to get all rows you have to do like this:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `wspm_t_colors`');
while($result = mysql_fetch_object($query))
{
    print json_encode($result);
}
```

mysql_fetch_object/array/row always returns only one row and moves the pointer to the next row, if there is no next row it returns false.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because mysql_fetch_object only returns a single row result. You need something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `wspm_t_colors`');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   \\access each result here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how you can have two rows in local

```
$array = array();
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `wspm_t_colors`');
while($result = mysql_fetch_object($query))
{
    $array[] = $result;
}
print json_encode($array);
```